# Error en JHipster: mvnw is not recognized as an internal or external command

Tags: java, jhipster

Como es sabido JHipster mezcla o une los dos mundos del desarrollo (Backend - Frontend), y mucho más !!!!  Como es un conglomerado de tantas tecnologías, podría dar la impresión que para comenzar a usarlo es necesario conocer con cierta profundidad por lo menos aquellas que usaremos en nuestro proyecto.

Sería muy bueno, ya que existe una herramienta así (que permite enfocar y llevar adelante un proyecto de desarrollo en toda su extensión), aprovecharla para iniciar a los desarrolladores en todo este ecosistema, y no que sea lo contrario, que ya tenga uno que conocer el ecosistema para poder usar JHipster.

Por lo menos yo, siguiendo el video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SoxR30Kkwj4, me topé rápidamente con un error al momento de intentar levantar
el backend (y no he podido resolver :( ) ¿Me podrían dar una luz acerca de lo que es?

> './mvnw': '.' is not recognized as an internal or external command
>
> '/mvnw': '/mvnw' is not recognized as an internal or external command
>
> 'mvnw': 'mvnw' is not recognized as an internal or external command

Lo probé de todas esas maneras y no me dejó. No sé si es que no tengo instalado Maven, o si tengo algún problema con Java, etc. Entonces en este caso, ya esto representó un freno para mí.

Answer (score 1):

Jhipster no necesita que tengas maven instalado, viene con el codigo  generado por jhipster cuando generas la aplicacion. Solo necesitas

- Instalar [Java 11](https://adoptopenjdk.net/)
- Instalar [NodeJs](https://nodejs.org/en/).
- Luego instalar el generador de jhipster `npm install -g generator-jhipster`.
- Luego
  crear la carpeta del proyecto `mkdir myapplication` , `cd
  myapplication/`
- Generar el proyecto con el comando `jhipster`,
  responder las preguntas.
- Y luego, para levantar el proyecto, correr
  `mvnw` si es Windows, y `./mvnw` si es mac o linux.

Mira https://www.jhipster.tech/installation/ la seccion de Quick Setup para mas informacion sobre la instalacion de jhipster y luego https://www.jhipster.tech/creating-an-app/ para generar una aplicacion